# isin not working for searching a subset of columns for unique values

Tags: python, pandas, isin

I have a data frame that have repetitions of some multiple column value combinations. I'm trying to extract the columns that have more than two repetitions. I have the following code

```
d = {'main_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'instant': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

uniqueCombinations = df.groupby(['main_id', 'type']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'Count'})
uniqueCombinations = uniqueCombinations.loc[uniqueCombinations['Count'] >= 3]
uniqueCombinations = uniqueCombinations.reset_index()
compare1 = df[['main_id', 'type']]
compare2 = uniqueCombinations[['main_id', 'type']]
mask = (compare1.isin(compare2)).all(axis=1)
```

What I do is to extract the rows that have `[1,1]` and `[3,2]` in the `main_id` and `type` columns in the df data frame. It's only matching only one row. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `compare1` and `compare2` datasets include the index of each row as a column.  So a value in `compare1` is only going to match up with a value in `compare2` if it is in the same position in the dataset as well as having the two column values match.  You can see this in the debugger.  Here's the state of these variables just before the line containing the `isin`:

```
compare1: [0 1 1] [1 1 1] [2 1 1] [3 2 1] [4 2 1] [5 3 2] [6 3 2] [7 3 2]
 
compare2: [0 1 1] [1 3 2]
```

So what you need to do is modify your code so that the first column value, the index of each row, is not part of the comparison.